# Adding the output of Stack.pop()

Tags: java

```js
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Stack;

public class Blackjack {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int cardValue; /* card value is from 2 to 11 */
    Stack Player1 = new Stack();
    Stack Addition = new Stack();

    Random r = new Random();
    int i = 2 + r.nextInt(11);

    System.out.println("Welcome to Mitchell's blackjack program!");

    for (int a = 1; a <= 2; a++) { /* Start's the game by assigning 2 cards each, to the players */
      Player1.push(i);
    }

    while (!Player1.empty()) {
      System.out.print("You get a " + Player1.pop());
      System.out.print("and");

      int sum = 0;

      for (int n = 0; n < Player1.size(); n++) {
        sum = sum + Player1.pop();
        System.out.print("Your total is " + sum);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So I just started learning java and I'm trying to accomplish this [BlackJack project](http://programmingbydoing.com/a/project-blackjack.html) But, when I try to compile using javac the output was bad operand types for binary operator '+' for the 'sum = sum + Player1.pop();'

The solution i used in the above coding was from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19487641/how-to-sum-elements-of-a-stack)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Player1.pop()` returns an `Object` because you used `Stack` without providing a type. and you cannot do `int + Object`. If you need to store `int`s in the Stack, just use generics and do

```
Stack<Integer> Player1 = new Stac<Integer>k();
Stack<Integer> Addition = new Stack<Integer>();
```

And your

```
System.out.print("Your total is " + sum);
```

should be outside the for otherwise you will get a temporary sum

Answer (score 0):

Change `Stack` to `Stack<Integer>`.

By default, you get a stack of (unknown) `Object`s, and you can't add an `Object` to an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Stack takes a generic argument that determines the type of Object that the Stack will store. This in turn defines the type of Object that pop() returns. In your case you could use a numeric type e.g.

`Stack Player1 = new Stack<Integer>();`

Providing no type argument will result in Object being returned and `int + Object` is not defined, hence your error.

Answer (score 0):

Others have explained this using Java generics, the new Stack() approach, which tells the compiler to only let you put Integers into the Stack, and automatically takes Integers out.

Before generics, you'd just cast whatever it was you brought out of the Stack to an Integer.  As people have said, the problem is that your code doesn't know what it's getting back from the stack, so it assumes Object, and doesn't know how to add those.  Casting would look like:

```
sum = sum + (Integer)Player1.pop();
```

Answer (score 0):

Although using Stack will solve this problem. But I guess there are issues the way you have used loop.

Your while loop will execute only once, as you for loop will empty that stack. Not sure if that's what you want to do.